# Hourly average for each week/month in dataframe (moving average)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, average, moving-average

I have a dataframe with full year data of values on each second:

```
YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS      TEMPERATURE (C)
2016-09-30 23:59:55.923       28.63
2016-09-30 23:59:56.924       28.61
2016-09-30 23:59:57.923       28.63
   ...                         ...
2017-05-30 23:59:57.923       30.02
```

I want to create a new dataframe which takes each week or month of values and average them over the same hour of each day (kind of moving average but for each hour).
So the result for the month case will be like this:

```
       Date         TEMPERATURE (C)
2016-09 00:00:00       28.63
2016-09 01:00:00       27.53
2016-09 02:00:00       27.44
   ...
2016-10 00:00:00       28.61
   ...                  ...
```

I'm aware of the fact that I can split the df into 12 df's for each month and use:

```
hour = pd.to_timedelta(df['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'].dt.hour, unit='H')
df2 = df.groupby(hour).mean()
```

But I'm searching for a better and faster way.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an alternate method of converting your date and time columns:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YYYY-MO-DD'] + ' ' + df['HH-MI-SS_SSS'])
```

Additionally you could `groupby` both week and hour to form a `MultiIndex` dataframe (instead of creating and managing 12 dfs):

```
df.groupby([df.datetime.dt.weekofyear, df.datetime.dt.hour]).mean()
```

[image]